# R: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' (time series forecasting)

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, forecasting

I am using the R programming language and am following this tutorial over here on time series forecasting: https://github.com/ahaeusser/echos

In this tutorial, the author shows how to use a type of neural network to predict future values of a time series.

Prior to beginning, many of the required packages can be downloaded from github:

```
devtools::install_github("ahaeusser/echos")
devtools::install_github("ahaeusser/tscv")
install.packages("fable")
remotes::install_github("tidyverts/fable")
remotes::install_github("tidyverts/tsibble")

#load libraries
library(echos)
library(tscv)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
#> [1] "C"
```

From here, I copy and pasted the author's code:

```
# Prepare dataset
data <- elec_price %>%
  tscv::clean_data()

# Setup for time series cross validation
n_init <- 2400   # size for training window
n_ahead <- 24    # size for testing window (forecast horizon)
mode <- "slide"  # fixed window approach
n_skip <- 23     # skip 23 observations
n_lag <- 0       # no lag

data <- data %>%
  tscv::split_data(
    n_init = n_init,
    n_ahead = n_ahead,
    mode = mode,
    n_skip = n_skip,
    n_lag = n_lag)

# Use only a small sample of data
data <- data %>%
  filter(BZN == "SE1") %>%
  filter(split == 10)
```

Here is where I run into an error:

```
models <- data %>%
  filter(sample == "train") %>%
  model(
    "ESN" = ESN(
      Value,
      inf_crit = "BIC",
      max_lag = 6,
      n_fourier = c(3, 3),
      n_initial = 50,
      n_res = 200,
      scale_inputs = c(-1, 1)),
    "sNaive" = SNAIVE(Value ~ lag("week")))
```

Error:

```
Warning message:
1 error encountered for ESN
[1] cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

In the above code, the author fits two different time series models. One of them works (the blue model), but the other model contains this error.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong? Or is there a problem in the background?

I also tried running the same code with some dummy data I created but I still get an error:

```
data = data.frame(rnorm(1000,100,100))
data$value = data$rnorm.1000..100..100.
data$rnorm.1000..100..100. = NULL

models <- data %>%
    filter(sample == "train") %>%
    model(
        "ESN" = ESN(
            Value,
            inf_crit = "BIC",
            max_lag = 6,
            n_fourier = c(3, 3),
            n_initial = 50,
            n_res = 200,
            scale_inputs = c(-1, 1)),
        "sNaive" = SNAIVE(Value ~ lag("week")))

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
i Input `..1` is `sample == "train"`.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A "closure" is just a function with its enclosing environment. This is a common error when somebody defines a variable named `data`, restarts R (without redefining the variable), and then tries to do something with that data.

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(value = rnorm(1000, 100, 100))
mean(data$value)
# [1] 97.41756
rm(data) ### or restart R
mean(data$value)
# Error in data$value : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

That's a root cause of most errors that include `'closure'`. It is similar in your case, I think.

First, a little efficiency, change your

```r
data = data.frame(rnorm(1000,100,100))
data$value = data$rnorm.1000..100..100.
data$rnorm.1000..100..100. = NULL
```

to

```r
data = data.frame(value = rnorm(1000,100,100))
```

no need for the frame-name-dance. And for the record, I used `set.seed(42)`, then defined this `data` frame, and then we see this:

```r
head(data)
#       value
# 1 237.09584
# 2  43.53018
# 3 136.31284
# 4 163.28626
# 5 140.42683
# 6  89.38755
```

Now, your next command ...

```r
data %>%
  filter(sample == "train")
# Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
# x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
# i Input `..1` is `sample == "train"`.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Where does `sample` come from? My guess is that you had a previous instantiation of `data` that contained more columns than just `value`. Namely, it had a column named `sample`.

In this case, however, where `data$sample` does not exist, `dplyr::filter` looks for the referenced symbols first in the respective frame (within `data`), and lacking that, searched in the global environment and the general R search path. It finds `sample`, aka `base::sample`, the function for sampling data.

So we go back to the premise that errors about 'closure':

```r
as.double(sample)
# Error in as.double(sample) : 
#   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

So whether it's literally attempting this internally or not, the bottom line is that you are likely referencing variables that are not present as columns in your frame.